# Creating and overwriting dataframe(lists) in a loop in Python

Tags: python, list, pandas

This is a powerful simplification of my earlier problem :)

There are 4 lists (In my case the values are integers):

```
e00 = [AB, CA]
e01 = [BD, FK]
e10 = [AC, DF]
e11 = [DE, FB]
```

next:

```
a = input('Write a binary number. \n')

    b = []
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        c = a[i:i+2]
        b.append(c)
```

For example, for string `00101`, I get:

```
b = ['00', '01', '10', '01']
```

Stages:

1. I choose the first two values in list `'b'`, ie `'00'` and `'01'`
2. For this reason, I will use lists `e00` and `e01`
3. I compare the above lists. My code just for this case:

   ```
   a00 = pd.DataFrame({'A':e00})
   a01 = pd.DataFrame({'B':e01})
   a10 = pd.DataFrame({'C':e10})
   a11 = pd.DataFrame({'D':e11})

       b = []
       for i in range(len(a)-1):
           c = a[i:i+2]
           b.append(c)

   if b[0]=='00':
      if b[1]=='01':

          m001 = a00.assign(x=a00.A.str[-1]).merge(a01.assign(x=a01.B.str[0], B=a01.B.str[1:]))

          v = (m001['A'] + m001['B'])
          v.str.len() == v.apply(set).str.len()
          c=v[v.str.len() == v.apply(set).str.len()].tolist()
   ```

Which gives:

```
c = [ABD]
```

4. I choose the third value from the list `'b'`, ie `'10'`
5. For this reason I will use `c and e10`
6. I compare the above lists.
7. I get `c = [ABDF]`
8. I choose the last fourth value in the list `'b'`, ie `'01'`
9. For this reason I will use `c and e01`
10. I compare the above lists.
11. Finally, I get `c = [ABDFK]`
12. End

I hope now the problem will be brighter :)

Comment: [mcve] if you can? Along with expected output, if you can reduce the explanation. Thanks!

Comment: @ cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ This fragment above works alone. just yet of course `import pandas as pd` :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ and only after typing '001'.

Comment: I believe coldspeed is asking for more readability, in particular, shorten the explanation and break into 2 or 3 smaller paragraphs instead of just one big one.  And often, just showing a simple example of desired output is easier to understand than a long explanation.

Comment: @JohnE just do not know how it's easier to explain eh :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ You read the 'b' list and take the first two values. The value of 'b' is assigned a data frame 'a' with the appropriate prefix. For them performs the above comparison operation. As a result, the 'c' list is created with the second value, ie '01'. Then you take another value from 'b', ie '10' and list 'a' with the corresponding prefix. And again you compare. And so on. Until the value of 'b' is exhausted. I do not know if it's clearer heh;)

Comment: And when I recently added a 'minimum question', they everyone said that flax ;)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ 'm001' is to merge two values from two lists with respect to the common border digit. At the same time remove one of them. For example [24] and [45] will give us [245].

Comment: I think I understood _exactly_ what you want. But I need one more point of clarification from you. What variables are to be chosen in the iteration after this?

Comment: I've posted an answer. The core concept is a dictionary mapping strings to variables.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I will post a new entry in a very simplified case. only those 90 minutes: /

Comment: You can just edit your current post.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I updated.

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski Okay, looks nice and clear. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you clearly, you're looking for a way to dynamically access `aXX` so you can then use them to perform your computation.

What you need is a *dictionary*.

```
dct = {'00' : a00, '01' : a01, '10' : a10, '11' : a11}    
c = dct[b[0]]

for i in b[1:]:
    d = dct[i]
    newcols = {'x' : d.iloc[:, 0].str[0], d.columns[0] : d.iloc[:, 0].str[1:]}
    m = c.assign(x=c.iloc[:, 0].str[-1]).merge(d.assign(**newcols))

    ... # rest of your code
```

You can use `b`'s elements to index into `dct` and extract the dataframes you need for that iteration.

Comment: you are great :) Everything works great on the above case. But I'm trying to modify it now for all frames `a00, a01, a10, a11`, because in each frame I fixed a different column name. And in 'm' only `A and B` are used.

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski You can refer to the first column with `df.iloc[:, 0]`.

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski I see the problem of dynamic columns is a bigger issue than I thought. So I'm initialising a dictionary of new columns and passing that to `d` after. It's easier. Take a look at my latest edit, I hope it helps.

Comment: However, I will still have to sit down for the night :) Since probably 'dict' blocks certain cases like "000". And the question of using longer binary strings is open. For now it works only on three digits :) But and anyway you helped me so much!